# How to give transparent background to bootstrap list group?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, list

I want to give a transparent background to a list group with only top border. Right now I get the default white background.

```
 <ul class="list-group">
     <li class="list-group-item">Cras justo odio</li>
     <li class="list-group-item">Dapibus ac facilisis in</li>
     <li class="list-group-item">Morbi leo risus</li>
     <li class="list-group-item">Porta ac consectetur ac</li>
     <li class="list-group-item">Vestibulum at eros</li>
 </ul>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

you can try this, it will work. Its easy may be you did not even tried.

```
.list-group-item {
background-color: transparent;
border-top: 1px solid #ddd;
border-radius: 0;
color: #fff;
}
```

Comment: It will leave a very bad outline in my case (newest Chrome browser).

Answer (score 16):

```
<ul class="list-group  bg-transparent">
 <li class="list-group-item  bg-transparent">Cras justo odio</li>
 <li class="list-group-item  bg-transparent">Dapibus ac facilisis in</li>
 <li class="list-group-item  bg-transparent">Morbi leo risus</li>
 <li class="list-group-item  bg-transparent">Porta ac consectetur ac</li>
 <li class="list-group-item  bg-transparent">Vestibulum at eros</li>
```

Comment: if you also don't want the lines add to each `<li>` the `border-0`

Answer (score 4):

The `.list-group-flush` will get rid of the borders and the rounded corners, leaving only a horizontal line between the list items to separate them from each other.

The `.bg-transparent` will make the background transparent

```
<ul class="list-group list-group-flush">
    <li class="list-group-item bg-transparent">Cras justo odio</li>
    <li class="list-group-item bg-transparent">Dapibus ac facilisis in</li>
    <li class="list-group-item bg-transparent">Morbi leo risus</li>
    <li class="list-group-item bg-transparent">Porta ac consectetur ac</li>
    <li class="list-group-item bg-transparent">Vestibulum at eros</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: if you also don't want the lines add to each `<li>` the `border-0`